# How to create a reorderable sibling relation in SQL? (order comments in a thread, songs in a playlist, etc)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, hierarchical-data

I have a system that requires data models which are 'siblings', all part of the same collection that users should be able to reorder.

Some concrete examples would be: A `playlist` containing many `songs`, an `album` containing many `photos`, a `blog` containing many `posts`, etc.

Because of other constraints, these data models are stored inside a relational SQL database.

However, relational databases do not naturally allow 'siblings' to be stored. I am looking for the correct approach to model the required invariants for this system in a relational database, especially when concurrent inserts/updates/deletions might happen.

**I know of the following approaches:**

**1)** Every `song` has a `order` integer column.

On insert: All songs part of a given `playlist` increment their `order`, the new song's `order` is set to `0`.

On delete: The required song column is removed; All songs above the given song's `order`'s `order` are decremented.

On changing the order: Increment/Decrement (depending on the new order value being lower/higher than the old order value) the order of all songs in-between the old and new position of the `song` column, and alter the order of the required song to the new index.

Main problem is that, unless you use serializeable transactions, the ordering might get messed up when multiple songs are added/moved at the same time, right? Any way to prevent this?

**2)** Every `song` has a `previous_song_id` column which points to its previous song, building something akin to a linked-list.

It seems to me that this is an antipattern that will cause N+1-query problems, but I am not sure of the queries involved of doing this in practice.

**3)** Store the order in an array field on the `playlist`. This does not have the problems of 1) or 2), but I am not sure how to only fetch the first `N` songs if the order depends on this array field. (i.e. how to write: `SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songs.playlist_id = 1, ORDER_BY ???, LIMIT 10`?)

**As mentioned above, all of these approaches have their drawbacks.**

I wonder if there are other ways to map a system like this to a relational database? Or how the drawbacks of one or more of these techniques can be mitigated?

These kinds of relations seem relatively common to me; I have encountered them multiple times but still do not know the proper approach to implement them. Nor do I actually know how to properly *call* such a system, other than something like  'ordered siblings relation'.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `relational databases do not naturally allow 'siblings' to be stored` I would say that this is false. One of the most common relational dbms can store and query those naturally. Here's a visualization from Oracle (I'm sure other dbms implement this similarly): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-3742/images/Encoder_Node_Relationships.gif 


By checking out hierarchical queries, you should be able to implement this easily (given you have a proper table structure).

Comment: @daZza I believe that in hierarchical queries, the ordering of siblings in the tree (hierarchy) is not preserved, but only the order between parents<->children.

Comment: Google '(hierarchical OR ordered) (data OR relation OR relationship OR association) sql'. Also entire books await you. PS Re "relational databases do not naturally allow 'siblings' to be stored", you are just not thinking relationally. When you think, 'the sibling after this one' or 'the nth sibling', or 'this one here in this picture', or 'the one after this one', those are names for a column: is_that_child_of(child, which, parent).

Comment: @philipxy So if I understand you correctly, you mean that the 'sibling' relationship could be modeled as a unary tree where each 'sibling' is a child of the previous 'sibling'? Isn't this analogous to the 'linked list'/'adjacency list' approach (which is considered an antipattern, according to the [SQL antipatterns book](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/trees.pdf) )?

Comment: Of course, let me add that 'something being an antipattern' doesn't mean that it is universally bad; you should pick and match your guarantees+limitations with smart consideration and there is no rule that is universally applicable. But querying adjacency lists to an arbitrary depth is something that SQL doesn't natively support (according to the antipatterns book, certain databases have extensions to allow this, but notably MySQL and SQLite do not) which makes it undesireable to use this technique for the purpose I intended, which was to allow (re)ordering of 100s of images in albums.

Comment: "*But querying adjacency lists to an arbitrary depth is something that SQL doesn't natively support*" - "SQL" supports this natively using recursive common table expression - this has been part of the standard since 2003 and all modern DBMS support them (even MySQL will arrive in the 21st century with the next release). In Oracle you additionally have `connect by` and `order siblings by`. Ordering the siblings can be achieved with a recursive CTE as well - it's just a bit more complicated

Comment: Re "you mean that the 'sibling' relationship could be modeled as a unary tree": No, because you are talking about a non-relation since its rows have order. What I meant was that contrary to the quoted claim, relations can directly model whatever relation[ship]s *you have in mind*. That ordered data structure *encodes* a *relation[ship] on siblings* like (per my last comment) "*this* sibling precedes *that* sibling" (which is a binary). (I am not arguing for or against any particular relation[ship]s/models for any particular usage patterns.)

Comment: @philipxy I see! Thank you for the clarification. Yes, you are right. :-)

Comment: Re "querying adjacency lists to an arbitrary depth": Hierarchies (hierarchical relation[ship]s) need CTEs/recursion/iteration when the number of JOINs to express a table, ie the number of ANDs to express a relationship, depends on the data. (Hence "arbitrary depth".) But the relationship "*this* sibling precedes *that* sibling ignoring *tother* sibling" only needs one (self-)JOIN of "*this* sibling precedes *that* sibling". (Anyway a *list* of siblings is only trivially hierarchical--it has no branches. So we can expect not the full complement of hierarchy issues.) (Try coding your designs.)